# Solving for a point using normal and tangent lines

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I've looked around and I couldn't find a similar example of this. So here is the question:

The line from the origin to the point *(a, f(a))* on the graph $$f(x) = 1/x^2$$ is perpendicular to the tangent line of the graph. What is *a*?

- I know the slope of the tangent line is the derivative $2x^{-3}$
- Thus I believe the slope of the normal line is $1/({-2x}^{-3}) $

Is that right? What would be my next step?

Comment: Slope of the tangent line at $(a,f(a))$ is $-2a^{-3}=-\dfrac{2}{a^3}$.

Answer (score 0):

That's almost correct, but the derivative is $-2x^{-3}$. It would probably be better to use $a$ at this point instead of $x$, since we're talking about the slope of the tangent line through $(a,f(a))$.

The normal line through the point $(a,f(a))$ has slope $a^3/2$. So you now just need to check whether the line from the origin to $(a,f(a))$ has that slope. If so, it will be the normal line; otherwise, it won't.

Answer (score 0):

Let $L$ be the line passing by $(0,0)$ and $(a,f(a))$, its slope is $m_L=\dfrac{f(a)}{a}=\dfrac{1}{a^3}$. So, if the tangent line to the curve by the point $(a,f(a))$ is perpendicular to $L$, it follows
\begin{align*}
m_L \left(-\dfrac{2}{a^3}\right)&=-1 \\
-\dfrac{2}{a^6}&=-1
\end{align*}
Solving for $a$ we get $a=\pm\sqrt[6]{2}$,

Comment: for the slope $f(a)/a = 1/a^3$, how did you get that?

Comment: Slope formula: $m=\dfrac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}=\dfrac{f(a)-0}{a-0}=\dfrac{f(a)}{a}=\dfrac{\frac{1}{a^2}}{a}=\dfrac{1}{a^3}$.